# por que el feof no funciona?

Tags: c, archivo

Estoy haciendo un proyecto final y me encontré con un problema en una parte del código, lo que trato de hacer es pasar información de un archivo txt a una estructura pero el programa se cierra sin saber el porque, creo que es feof pero no se como corregirlo, también intente for( i = 0; feof(archivo) == 0; i++) con los mismos resultados y for(i = 0; fgetc(archivo) != EOF; i++) con el problema que no se guarda el primer carácter.

```
    FILE *archivo = fopen(NombreArchivoUsuarios,"r+");  

    while (!feof (archivo))
    {
        fgets(temporal,50,archivo);
        cont++;
    }
    
    aux = (Nodo*) malloc (cont * sizeof(Nodo));
    
    if(aux == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error en reserva de memoria 01");
        system("pause");
    } 
    
    rewind (archivo);       
    for(i = 0; !feof(archivo); i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<50; j++)
        {
            temporal[j] = '\0';
        }
        
        aux1 = '0'; 
        
        for (otro_contador = 0; aux1 != '\n'; otro_contador++)
        {
            aux1 = fgetc(archivo);
            temporal[otro_contador] = aux1; 
        }
        
        n = strlen(temporal) + 1;
        aux[i].user = (char*) malloc (n* sizeof(char));
        
        if (aux[i].user == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error en reserva de memoria 02");
            system("pause");
        }
        
        strcpy(aux[i].user, temporal);
        CONTADOR_USUARIOS++;    
     }

     fclose(archivo);           
    }
```

Comment: *"for(i = 0; fgetc(archivo) != EOF; i++) con el problema que no se guarda el
primer carácter."*. Y si pruebas con algo estilo: `for (int i = 0, c =
fgetc(archivo); c != EOF; i++, (c = fgetc(archivo)))`?. Con el codigo que compartes es muy dificil ayudarte, ya que para este tipo de problemas tenemos que correr el codigo en nuestras maquinas, usar un debuger, algun sanitizer, etc, cosa que no es posible de momento. Comparte suficiente codigo como para que podamos copiar, pegar, y reproducir tu probelma, y recuerda incluir tambien el archivo del que estas leyendo.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo lo intentaré, el problema con compartir el código es que muy largo consta de 3000 líneas de código. no se si pueda subir en archivo

Comment: En ese caso te recomendaría que leyeras [este articulo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Tendrías que crear un ejemplo mas pequeño que reproduzca el problema, y a base de eso podemos tratar de ayudarte.